# Inaccessible due to protection level in C#

Tags: c#

I have references `object` which contains abstract `LoggerFile` class. I am trying to access it. But it is showing inaccessible due to `protection` level. Please anyone help me to understand it.

```
abstract class LoggerFile
{
     private static String logFile = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Logfile Property
        /// </summary>
        public static string LogFile { get => logFile; set => logFile = value; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Set logFile
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="logFile">The absolute path to file for writting logs</param>
        public static void SetLogFile(String logFile)
        {
            LogFile = LogFile ?? logFile;
            if (!File.Exists(LogFile))
            {
                File.Create(LogFile).Close();
            }
            }
}
}
```

I am calling this in another class.

```
using DriverAutomation.Loggin[enter image description here][1]g;
    public class Devcon
    {
        private static Devcon devcon = null;

        private readonly String devconEXE;
    private readonly String devconPath;
    private readonly String devconExeName;
    private readonly Logger logger;

    /// <summary>
    ///     DevconStatus Property for devcon status outcome backup
    /// </summary>
    public readonly String devconStatus;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes the Devcon Singleton Instance
    /// </summary>
    private Devcon()
    {
        devcon = this;
        logger = Logger.GetLogger(GetType().Name, LoggerFile.LogFile);
        devconExeName = "devcon.exe";
        devconEXE = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), devconExeName);
}
}
```

This is working within created solution. But using reference object it is showing error. Please find image.

Comment: What line is the error shown at?

Comment: Exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Parameter callerClassName must not be null or empty or exclusively of white-space characters.

Comment: Logger file is inaccessible due to protection level

Comment: Try make it  "public abstract class LoggerFile" , this may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your class as public and non-Abstract and I think it will solve your problem.

```
public class LoggerFile
```

By the way, why is it even `Abstract`. If you only have some static members in it, maybe you should just turn it to static itself.

Though in most logger implementations, it makes sense to follow the singleton pattern (one of the few cases)

Comment: Even i tried with declaring it as public class. But still is showing inaccessable.

Comment: Remove the abstract please and try again.

Comment: after removing abstract keyword it is not throwing any error. Thank you @Athanasios Kataras.